# How to repair/show missing dbs list in TokuMX MongoDB that have files in dbpath?

Tags: tokumx

I wanted to copy the data files (not mongodump) of one mongodb instance to another and here's the scenario:

1. Shutdown MongoDB on Machine 1 and copied the db files to Machine 2
2. Shutdown MongoDB on Machine 2
3. Moved the copied data files from Machine 1 to the dbpath of MongoDB on Machine 2
4. Started MongoDB on Machine 2

Now when I execute `show dbs` it doesn't list any of the dbs that were previously there and of course neither the db that has been copied.

Now that I know this doesn't work, I wanted to rollback the changes done on Machine 2. So I shutdown the instance, removed the copied files and restarted but I still don't see any of the dbs that were previously there. Tried to search everywhere on how to repair this to no avail. How can this be fixed?

Note: I tried the --repair parameter on mongod but it's depricated on TokuMX v1.4.1-mongodb-2.4.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to restore the data by using `mongodump` with `--dbpath` which allowed me to create backups of dbs directly from the database files instead of the mongod server (the server has to be offline for this to work). Then I was able to use `mongorestore` to load the data to a new instance.

I had to use mongodb-org instead of tokumx for this to work (with tokumx the dumps came out empty).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to copy just a subset of one server to another, everything must be copied to the new server.

If you want to move a single collection or all collections in a particular database then you need to use mongodump/mongorestore.

Comment: Yes I got that after the error was done. My concern now is how to restore the dbs that were on Machine 2? I already removed the files I copied but why wouldn't it go back to normal? Instead I see none of the databases although their files are there

Comment: You'd need to recover from a backup (prior to the file movements).

Comment: I've managed to restore the data as explained in my answer. Thanks for taking the time to help @tmcallaghan :)